# (mysql) What type of encoding do I need to store this kind of character

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a site which handles user logins through Steam and some usernames can have weird characters in them and whenever I try to update/insert them I get the #1366 - Incorrect string value error. For example I had a query fail because of this:

What's the best way of handling this? Change the encoding? Filter them out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use utf8mb4 that stands for 4-byte utf8 unicode encoding. You have to make sure:

- Your application supports this encoding as well.
- In the machine you want to retrieve data you set `SET NAMES utf8mb4` before running any queries.

More information can be found in:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html